# Set onclick from JS

Tags: javascript, function, styles

I try to add some html code (from JS) in some variable, after I need change style and set onclick method this element.

```
var sideBar = document.createElement('div');
sideBar.setAttribute("class", "sidenav");
sideBar.setAttribute("id", "mySidenav");

sideBar.innerHTML = `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>`;

sideBar.innerHTML += `<span onclick="openNav()">pen</span>`;

function openNav() {
    sideBar.style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    sideBar.style.width = "0px";
}
```

But JS always says that `openNav()` and `closeNav()` are undefined. And I know that I can write html code in *.html, but in this case I need add html code from JS.

Comment: Because they are not in global scope assuming that code is actually in a method.

Comment: @epascarello I should create these functions in `window.onload = function(){..}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a specific task, since I tried to make extension for Google Chrome. The `addEventListener(...)` solved the problem.

```
    var btn = document.createElement('a');
    btn.setAttribute("id", "btn_1");
    btn.setAttribute("class", "ui_rmenu");
    btn.textContent = "Open";

    btn.addEventListener("click", openNav);

    function openNav(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works! I only added this line: document.body.appendChild(sideBar);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        var sideBar = document.createElement('div');
        sideBar.setAttribute("class", "sidenav");
        sideBar.setAttribute("id", "mySidenav");

        document.body.appendChild(sideBar); // <---

        sideBar.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>';
        sideBar.innerHTML += '<span onclick="openNav()">pen</span>';

        function openNav() {
            sideBar.style.width = "250px";
            console.log("open");
        }

        function closeNav() {
            sideBar.style.width = "0px";
            console.log("close");
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It did not work, I tried to do something like this...